# Event in Style Resource not firing. Why?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mouseevent

I have a very specific situation where I need to disable focusable in a List Box, but then the items inside it cannot be selected.
So I added an EventSetter in the item style to send a notification that it has been clicked so I switch to it behind the scenes, but the event isnt firing up.

Any help in making it work is much appreciated!

Heres the full xaml style code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style
        x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle"
        BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}"
        TargetType="ListBoxItem">

        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <!--  Fixes spacebar not working and some other bugs if selecting via mouse  -->
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
        <EventSetter
            Event="MouseDown"
            Handler="OnThumbnailSelect" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `PreviewMouseDown` event instead.

Comment: Yup, thanks. I figured that out a bit after I asked the question xD

Comment: why doesn't the MouseDown event fire?  Why do you need to use PreviewMouseDown?

Comment: @MattNewcomb behind the scenes a listbox is really just a container (vertical StackPanel by default) with a list of items, to which it adds some additional functionality (notably the ability to select them). The focusable property is how it distinguishes between which items can be selected and which ones can't, which in turn dictates which ones can raise a MouseDown event. PreviewMouseDown gives you a way to preemptively detect the click before the MouseDown event goes through its own handlers.